# How do I structure Laravel models and resources when using reference tables?

Tags: laravel

I'm still getting used to Laravel concepts, particularly with Models and Resources.
I'm having trouble wrapping my head around how to implement these concepts within my project the proper Laravel way, given what I have below.

I have the following tables as examples:

```
applicants: {id, full_name, date_of_birth, applicant_type_id}
applciant_types: {id, applicant_type_name}
```

Currently, I've created an Applicant model and made an Applicant resource as well.

In my Applicant resource, I'm running a raw SQL query to store the collection of applicant types and then using the *applicant* record's *applicant_type_id* to get the *applicant_type_name* from the *applicant_types* collection.

How can I achieve this using native features of Models and Resources? By doing it as I currently am, will it affect performance if I have many references like this on one table and I try to query for a collection of the resource?

Thank you

Comment: Have you made the relationships in models?

Comment: How would I set the relationships up, given my table structure?

It seems to expect me to also store an applicant_id in my applicant_types table.

Comment: added an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel has very well documented these processes (https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#the-save-method). But, here is a summary.

Assuming that your model names are `Applicant` and `ApplicantType`, `Applicant::class` belongs to `ApplicantType::class`. Therefore, you can setup the relationship in `Applicant` model like so:

```
use App\ApplicantType;
..
public function applicant_type()
{
   return $this->belongsTo(ApplicantType::class);
}
```

And, ApplicantType has many Applicant. Relationship in ApplicantType model is:

```
use App\Applicant;
..
public function applicants()
{
   return $this->hasMany(Applicant::class);
}
```

When these relationships are set, you can use eloquent to save and retrieve data. For example,

```
$applicant = new Applicant(["full_name" => "John Doe", "date_of_birth"=>"1990-12-12"]);
$applicant_type = ApplicantType::create(["Type One"]); //make sure fillable array is set.
$applicant_type->applicants()->save($applicant);
```

That's one way. Do read through the documentation. It will give you loads of more information. Also, on a different note, do not use `timestamp` (if you are using that is) to store birth dates. I have so many laravel newbies do this and coming across invalid date exceptions. Timestamp will not allow you to store dates before 1970. So use `DATE` instead.

Hope this response would point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you! You made me realize where I had gone wrong. I had an okay grasp of relating the models from the documentation. 

But what I did differently from you was that I made it so that an applicant had one applicant_type, rather than making it so it belonged to one, which lead to the confusion and errors.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the vast amount of ways retrieving the records can be done, I **highly** recommend reading up on the many different ways you can use this with the [Official Laravel Documents Located Here](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships).

Assuming that an `Applicant` can have `One` `Applicant Type`:

`Applicant` Model

```php
public function type()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\ApplicantType');
}
```

`ApplicantType` Model

```php
public function applicant()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Applicant');
}
```

Now assuming that the `applicant_types` table is already populated, and the `applicants` table already has the correct `applicant_type_id` populated, you can retrieve them with Eloquent using several different methods.

```php
$applicantType = Applicant::find(1)->type;
```

The above will first get the applicant from the `applicants` table with the id of 1, and then it will look at that applicants `applicant_type_id` to get the corresponding applicant type record from the `applicant_types` table.